# How to represent custom spring cloud stream kafka binder configuration in Java auto configuration

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have the following configuration with custom kafka binder configurations

```
spring.cloud.stream:
  bindings:
    inputBinding1:
      binder: kafka1
      destination: destination1
    inputBinding2:
      binder: kafka2
      destination: destination2
  binders:
    kafka1:
      type: kafka
      environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder:
        brokers: hostname1
    kafka2:
      type: kafka
      environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder:
        brokers: hostname2
```

I want to represent spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka1 and spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka2 in Java as Spring Beans in a shareable library. The goal being to provide boilerplate Kafka cluster configuration such as brokers and consumer/producer properties. I'd like the ability to use either binder individually or multi binder

Comment: were you able to figure out a way to do this?